# How to submit missed LIC premium receipt and reimburse in Tax filing using cleartax.in

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, income-tax-refund, electronic-filing

I missed to submit one of my LIC premium receipt for reimbursement. As the deadline is over and I am filing using clearTax.in site, Does anyone know how to submit the LIC premium receipt and get reimbursement for the same. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIC payments come under section 80C.
You would need to fill in the total deductions [including the LIC payment that you did not claim] in this 80C section. There is no need to attach the receipts. In case the there is query by tax department, keep the receipt handy. Generally there are no queries.

Comment: Thanks. I have submitted as you mentioned. Hope they wont ask for query